# Analyzing factorial loop in Java

Tags: java, loops, for-loop, logic

Consider the following code:

```
int number;
double factorial = 1.0;

for(int i=2; i<=5; i++)
{
    factorial *=i;
    System.out.println(number + "! = " + factorial );
}
```

Why is the output

```
2.0
6.0
24.0
120.0
```

I know it starts from 2 until 5.

Comment: The question is not clear, but the reason why you see 2.0 instead of 2 is because factorial is a double, not an integer. By default it will print out like this.

Comment: Do you know what factorial is? did you know that 4!=24 and 5!=120?

Comment: Like @ergonaut said, it's not a very clear question. Edit it to address your specific question about the relevant code, and show the full output, not a truncated version.

Comment: I intend to multiply by a double, but the thing that I could not understand yet is why I got 6.0 / 24.0 / 120.0 cuz I know 1.0*2=2.0  second  is supposed to be 1.0*3=3.0, but instead I got 6.0    WHY??? Also for the rest 24.0 and 120.0

Comment: How do you get an output..? Code must be compile error. variable number is not initialized..

Comment: @ForlanAnWest, the second time around the loop, factorial keeps the value of 2.0.  It doesn't get reset to 1.0.  This variable stays in memory and does not clear.

Comment: Because after the folirst iteration of the loop, "factorial" becomes 2.0 and in the next iteration it is like 2.0 * 3 = 6.0 which is according to mathematical definition of factorial

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
factorial *=i;
```

means factorial =i*factorial;

factoial variable scope is relay outside of loop so it it not reset on every loop iteration

so when i=2 that time factorial = 2.0

when i=3 that time factorial value is 2.0 calculated above so factorial = 2.0*3 i.e 6

when i=4 that time factorial = 6*4 =24.0

when i=5 that time factorial = 24*5 = 120.0

Comment: factorial  takes the result of the previous one. ie    when i=2, 1.0*2=2.0 and then factorial uses 2.0 to * to 3 and so on .

Answer (score 0):

```
factorial *= i;
```

is equivalent to :

```
factorial = factorial * i;
```

Let's say `factorial` is `1.0` and `i` is `2` :

Well the calculus will be :

```
factorial = 1.0 * 2
```

And so on til the end of the loop.

Comment: Nice but why did i return   in 3=6.6 and 4=24.0 and 5=120.0  ?

Comment: @ForlanAnWest What was the question then? :)

Comment: Because after the folirst iteration of the loop, "factorial" becomes 2.0 and in the next iteration it is like 2.0 * 3 = 6.0 which is according to  mathematical definition of factorial

Answer (score 0):

I think you wanted to use a `long` (not a `double` and it's because you use a `double` that you get a floating-point type). Factorial is usually of integral type. Something like,

```
long factorial = 1;
for (int i = 2; i <= 5; i++) {
    factorial *= i;
    System.out.println(i + "! = " + factorial);
}
```

And I get (the expected)

```
2! = 2
3! = 6
4! = 24
5! = 120
```

Comment: I intend to multiply by a double, but the thing that I could not understand yet is why I got 6.0 / 24.0 / 120.0 cuz I know 1.0*2=2.0 second is supposed to be 1.0*3=3.0, but instead I got 6.0 WHY??? Also for the rest 24.0 and 120.0

Comment: @ForlanAnWest No, the second is 2*3. And the third is 4*3*2.

Answer (score 0):

```
int number;


for(int i=2; i<=5; i++)
{
  double factorial = 1.0;
  factorial *=i;
  System.out.println(number + "! = " + factorial );
}
```

The code above will give output 2.0, 3.0 ... because with every iteration in loop new variable 'factorial' will be created and initialized to 1.0

but with

```
int number;
double factorial = 1.0;

for(int i=2; i<=5; i++)
{
factorial *=i;
System.out.println(number + "! = " + factorial );
}
```

for i=2

factorial = factorial *i // ie. 1.0 *2  = 2.0; new value of factorial is    2.0 ie. factorial = 2.0

for i=3

factorial = factorial *3 // ie. 2.0 * 3 =6.0 ; which is factorial (when i=1) times 3

for i=4

factorial = factorial(when i=2) * 4 // ie. 6.0 *4 = 24.0

Answer (score -1):

- 1*2 = 2
- 2*3 = 6
- 6*4 = 24
- 24*5 = 120

I guess, the output is right only

1,2,6,24 are result stored in factorial var during prior iteration

2,3,4,5 are for loop i value